# Async.js event for progress tracking

Tags: javascript, events, task, async.js

I´m using async.js to execute some tasks in a series

```
async.series([task1,task2,task3,....],
   function(error,result){
      //Called after everything is finished
});
```

The default event listener only handles the finished event, but I want to track the finish event of each single task in order to track the total progress of my job.

Is it possible to register that kind of event listener without manually implementing events within each task itself?